# How to find Which Button is clicked in android?

Tags: android-layout

I have two Layouts(LineatLayOut).Each layout contains three buttons.Three buttons of first layout uses the variable `teamA`.Three buttons of Second layout uses the variable `teamB`. I am confused which button is clicked. I tried to get the id by `view.getId()` but it returns some integer values.How can I find which button is clicked???

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
        >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/teamA"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
                android:layout_margin="25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="Team A"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    android:id="@+id/teamAScore"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:id="@+id/teamA3Button"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="#F57F17"
                    android:onClick="addScoreOne"
                    />
                <Button
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="#F57F17"
                    />
                <Button
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:background="#F57F17"
                    android:text="FREE THROUGH"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>


            <View
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="1dp"

                android:background="@android:color/black"
                />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/teamB"
            android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
            android:layout_margin="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:text="Team B"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:id="@+id/teamBScore"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="3"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="#F57F17"
                />
            <Button
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="5"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="#F57F17"
                />
            <Button
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Free Through"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="#F57F17"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>>
     <Button
         android:text="Reset"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="#F57F17"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:textColor="@android:color/black"
         android:layout_margin="10dp"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

code for addScoreone:

```
    public void addScoreOne(View view)
    {
        
       if (view.getId()==R.id.teamA3Button)
        {
            teamAScore+=3;

            aTextView=findViewById(R.id.teamAScore);
            aTextView.setText(teamAScore);

        }
       else
       {
           teamBScore+=3;
           aTextView=findViewById(R.id.teamBScore);
           aTextView.setText(teamBScore);
       }

    }
```

Comment: Hi Priya Kavi, could you please add the code of the `addScoreOne` Method, which you defined in you activity. This will help us to solve the problem. Thank you!

Comment: I have updated.

Comment: I think if you assigned the `onClick="addScoreOne"` just to the `teamA3Button`, the code in your else construct will never reached. But a click on the `teamA3Button` worked as expected as i tested your code yesterday... Does it work now or are there still problems?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `id` and `onClick` attribute to to each button xml. Then you can detect each button in the code using button id like `R.id.teamB5Button` in your `addScoreOne` method.